# Python3: Convert List of Complex Objects to CSV

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, csv, dictionary

TL;DR: How do I convert a complex object to CSV in python3?

Longer version:

I'm dumping a vendor's database (so I can't control what I receive) using python3.6.  I can extract the JSON into a list of dicts.  Dict has multiple value datatypes, including string, int, sub-list, and sub-dict.

How do I convert this to CSV?

Sample data (pKey = Parent Key, dKey = Daughter Key):

```
[ { "pKey1" : 1, "pKey2" : [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], "pKey3" : { "dKey1" : "val1", "dKey2" : "val2" } },
  { "pKey1" : 2, "pKey2" : [ 'd' ],           "pKey3" : { "dKey1" : "val3", "dKey2" : "val4" } } 
]
```

How would I convert that to CSV?  I'm reading that there's a pythonic way to share complex data structures between python scripts (I think miltiprocess.manage or something like that), but the scripts are launched from BASH they know nothing of each other, and I have a need at the moment to capture the server's output in CSV to be able to read the data in Excel or Notepad (`my-machine:~ /home/myuser$ python3 script1.py | tee file.csv | python3 script2.py`).

I tried simply dumping the table through module csv, but the output is awkward:

```
pKey1,pKey2,pKey3
1,"['a', 'b', 'c']","{'dKey1': 'val1', 'dKey2': 'val2'}"
2,"['d']","{'dKey1': 'val3', 'dKey2': 'val4'}"
```

I tried pandas, but that doesn't flatting everything, which is still awkward, and the dict gets flattened weird which makes it awkward two ways:

```
pKey1,pKey2,pKey3.dKey1,pKey3.dKey2
1,"['a', 'b', 'c']",val1,val2
2,"['d']",val3,val4
```

I can make either of these work for today through ugly code, ugly reading, or both.  However, I'm concerned that future code maintainers would struggle with the code (I work in a network shop, not a software shop, so I need minimal complexity), and I'm concerned future work reading the CSV and trying to recreate the vendor's original data structure would have a hard time of it.

I know "one" way Excel is able to visualize the data using the merge-cells feature, but I don't know how to encode that in CSV:

[image]

I suppose I could write my own routine to flatten the object, but I don't relish that thought - a future vendor software upgrade may change the data structure, and anyway it's unclear it would be supportable by my peers. I'm hoping there's a more pythonic approach I can take.

I know sample code is normally expected, but I'm not even sure what direction to take.

As an added bonus, not necessarily specific to this question but rather an outgrowth of it.  The vendor is nice, in that at least the data is well-behaved; that is, the structure is consistent from one element to the next.  This here would really make a mess of things, is there a way to handle this as well?

```
# row 1: dict with two keys; row 2: dict with 3 keys
[ { "pKey1" : 1, "pKey2" : { "dKey1" : "val1", "dKey2" : "val2" } },
  { "pKey1" : (2, 3), "pKey2" : "This is different", "pKey3" : [ "Very", ( "Very", "Different" ) ] } 
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more reading and more thinking, I came to the realization that I'm mis-interpreting the challenge.  I'm not trying to dump a CSV of complex data.  I'm trying to represent complex data in CSV format.

Unfortunately, CSV is good specifically and only when each row is a dictionary of key:value pairs of data, ideally with common keys() in each row (where the keys() are also known as "column headings").  If it's in any way more complicated than that, then a CSV is and always will be the wrong tool to use.

JSON, while not necessarily openable in Excel, is a much better serialization format to represent complex data.  Still not perfect, but I suspect there's no better standard data representation format, and it's at least readable (especially with the json.dump() "indent" parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas.json_normalize` and `DataFrame.explode`, pandas 1.3.2:

```
# Your example data
d = [{"pKey1": 1, 
      "pKey2": ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
      "pKey3": {"dKey1": "val1", 
                 "dKey2": "val2"}},
     {"pKey1": 2, 
      "pKey2": ['d'],           
      "pKey3": {"dKey1": "val3", 
                "dKey2": "val4"}} 
]

df = pd.json_normalize(d)

print(df)

   pKey1      pKey2 pKey3.dKey1 pKey3.dKey2
0      1  [a, b, c]        val1        val2
1      2        [d]        val3        val4

# Split up the lists in pKey2, giving each item its own row
res = df.explode('pKey2')

print(res)

   pKey1 pKey2 pKey3.dKey1 pKey3.dKey2
0      1     a        val1        val2
0      1     b        val1        val2
0      1     c        val1        val2
1      2     d        val3        val4
```

The result is a flat table, but contains repetition of some values across rows, which may or may not work for you.

Comment: An interesting way of approaching this.  Certainly solves how to flatten an embedded list that is the value of one of the key/value pairs, and if I understand correctly it also doesn't require before-hand knowledge of the data schema.  I had thought I might've had a cognitive error, as CSV files are a list of key:value pairs, making them generally unsuitable for anything more complex.  But, let me test this, see how well it works against several of the production data sets I'm evaluating - it's absolutely an interesting approach!

Comment: I tested this out.  Very interesting, however I was in error and it does in fact require special knowledge about the schema.  It also only know how to handle exploding a single key (I think?), and only explode() one level so a value that is a list of lists doesn't explode fully.

Ultimately I'm left with the realization that CSV, while nice, is limited in that it's not suitable as a general-purpose data serializer, with JSON being much better when it's not a simple single-level list of dictionaries, with strings in all keys and values.